# How can I produce string with double quotes and write it to a text file

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have tried so much but so far unable to produce a string like this using c#

> Sku_id("5ac5d5fd754bc84f45786dd6")

I am trying to do something like this but unable to get the desired result, can anyone suggest what should I do.

```
var skuCode = "5ac5d5fd754bc84f45786dd6";

var skuId= "sku_id(" + '\u0022' + skuCode  + '\u0022' + ")");
```

The above code always produces the string like this which is not what I want

> "sku_id(\"5ac5d5fd754bc84f45786dd6\")"

I want to produce a string and write to a text file like this

> sku_id("5ac5d5fd754bc84f45786dd6")

Comment: How are you observing the string? In the debugger or in the actual file? The debugger will add slashes to inform you that it's an actual quote character and not the end of the string (ans  makes it handy for copy/paste operations).

Comment: You can also do `var skuId= @"sku_id("""+ skuCode  + @""")");` but the view in the debugger will be the same

Comment: Actually that code wont compile...

Comment: Try this: `var skuId = "sku_id("\"" + skuCode + "\")";`

Comment: Try something like this:  `var skuId= $"sku_id(\"{skuCode}\")";`

Comment: Your code is fine, remove the extra `)` at the end of `skuid` ... D Stanley mentions its the debugger that does this...

Comment: Guys, what ever I do, in the text file it is writing the string along with "\" which is really I am not looking for.